# Create varying number of rows per ID based on condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one row per ID. I'm trying to create multiple rows per ID with the same information except `start` and `stop`.

If age >= 36, this ID should have a total of 9 rows. `start` should be 27, 28,..., 35. `stop` should be 28, 29,..., 36.

If 27 > age < 36, this ID should have (`age` - 27) total rows. For example, if `age` is 30, then this ID should have a total of 3 rows.

If age = 27, this ID should have a total of 1 row. The youngest age in my dataset is 27, so each ID should have at least 1 row.

Some data:

```
df$id <- c(1, 2, 3)
df$age <- c(27, 40, 30)
time.columns <- c("start", "stop")
df[, time.columns] <- NA
```

I want it to look like:

```
id age start stop 
1  27  27    28 
2  40  27    28
2  40  28    29
2  40  29    30 
2  ..  ..    ..
2  40  35    36
3  30  27    28 
3  30  28    29 
3  30  29    30
```

Comment: @akrun It looks like `stop <- start + 1`.

Comment: Yes, that's right. `stop` should be `start` + 1

Comment: Based on the expected output showed, I think it is 13 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a basic `if` ... `else` function for the "age" values and use that to calculate the "start" columns. Something like this should get you started:

```
expander <- function(value) {
  if (value >= 36) {
    start = 27:35
  } else if (value == 27) {
    start = 27
  } else if (value > 27 & value < 36) {
    start = 27 + sequence(value - 27) - 1
  }
}
```

Here's how you can use it:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 age = c(27, 40, 30, 29))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(start = list(expander(age))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(start)) %>% 
  mutate(stop = start + 1)
# # A tibble: 15 x 4
# # Groups:   id [4]
#       id   age start  stop
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1    27    27    28
#  2     2    40    27    28
#  3     2    40    28    29
#  4     2    40    29    30
#  5     2    40    30    31
#  6     2    40    31    32
#  7     2    40    32    33
#  8     2    40    33    34
#  9     2    40    34    35
# 10     2    40    35    36
# 11     3    30    27    28
# 12     3    30    28    29
# 13     3    30    29    30
# 14     4    29    27    28
# 15     4    29    28    29
```

---

If you want to stick with base R all the way, you can do:

```
x <- with(df, sapply(age, expander))

within(df[rep(1:nrow(df), lengths(x)), ], {
    start = unlist(x)
    stop = start + 1
})
##     id age stop start
## 1    1  27   28    27
## 2    2  40   28    27
## 2.1  2  40   29    28
## 2.2  2  40   30    29
## 2.3  2  40   31    30
## 2.4  2  40   32    31
## 2.5  2  40   33    32
## 2.6  2  40   34    33
## 2.7  2  40   35    34
## 2.8  2  40   36    35
## 3    3  30   28    27
## 3.1  3  30   29    28
## 3.2  3  30   30    29
## 4    4  29   28    27
## 4.1  4  29   29    28
```

Comment: Thank you - why do we need to use `list()` on the expander function?

Comment: @user12310746, it creates a `list` column that can be `unnest`ed later. `mutate` expects the resulting number of rows to be the same as the input, but that's not the case with this function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  .(start = 27:pmin(pmax(age - 1, 27), 35)),
  .(id, age)
][
  ,
  stop := start + 1
][]
```

which gives

```
    id age start stop
 1:  1  27    27   28
 2:  2  40    27   28
 3:  2  40    28   29
 4:  2  40    29   30
 5:  2  40    30   31
 6:  2  40    31   32
 7:  2  40    32   33
 8:  2  40    33   34
 9:  2  40    34   35
10:  2  40    35   36
11:  3  30    27   28
12:  3  30    28   29
13:  3  30    29   30
```

Answer (score 1):

As the 'start' remains fixed, we create the 'stop' based on the minimum value of 36 and the 'age', create a sequence from 'start' and 'stop', then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
   mutate(start = 27, stop = map2(start+1, pmin(36, age), 
    ~ if(.y > .x) seq(.x, .y) else .x)) %>% 
   unnest(c(stop)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(start = first(start) + row_number() - 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
#      id   age start  stop
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    27    27    28
# 2     2    40    27    28
# 3     2    40    28    29
# 4     2    40    29    30
# 5     2    40    30    31
# 6     2    40    31    32
# 7     2    40    32    33
# 8     2    40    33    34
# 9     2    40    34    35
#10     2    40    35    36
#11     3    30    27    28
#12     3    30    28    29
#13     3    30    29    30
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, age = c(27, 40, 30)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```